# Need guide with XML Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I need help with something that sounds easy but has given me some trouble.
i have an assignment to do to be an automation using xml Transformation but i dont know where to start .

I have xml file which have all employes and have another text file which have login details see pictures.

the new XML should do:

**Compare** the number from   with the text file if it has a match then **will add a new code line inside**

then generate a **new XML file**

code

```
<person>
      <comments>Persondata - Anställd</comments>
      <sourcedid>
         <source>P5ta</source>
         <id>2011041910</id>
      </sourcedid>
      <userid password="">POH</userid>
      <name>
         <fn>HelPost, Pla</fn>
         <n>
            <family>HelPost</family>
            <given>Pla</given>
         </n>
      </name>
      <email/>
      <tel teltype="Voice">0675-19715</tel>
      <tel teltype="Mobile">0215-14195</tel>
      <adr>
         <street>rah 26</street>
         <street/>
         <street>237 53 Paos</street>
      </adr>
      <institutionrole institutionroletype="STAFF" primaryrole="Yes"/>
      <extension>
         <ssn>191919188291912</ssn>
      </extension>
      
   </person>
```

/////

login file contain

> AAE268097B0C24F9C2C1D4E75B7111EB;198204199050;Albin
> Hfund;Björfd;adn.hafnd.bsund@moai.se;;Student;FT14;/Elever/Gymnasieskolan;Elev;;;
> B487CB1D9F463455256D7D6CBB9DE8C1;1924061134;Aleqnder
> Tomqsz;Andruszqwicz;alerder.toqsz.andruszkieq@lpioa.se;;Student;EK2;/Elever/Gymnasieskolan;Elev;;;

I hope you give me some guide how to do it

[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEOvx.jpg)

[login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFNQL.jpg)

Comment: 1. Please post all the code  **as code** within your question, not as pictures in external links. 2. Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for your replay as i mention privose i need a guide 
what to learn to make it, i dont need someone to write code, it will be very hopefull if you say to me where to begin, thanks again